# Test for connected graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I have implemented a union find algorithm that finds and joins an undirected graph with vertexes that are represented by integers. I want to know if someone has any psuedocode or an idea on how to see if components "connected" ie there is a path that goes from one node to another. For example, I have the following vertexes:

7 (source vertex), 9 (destination vertex) and 8 (source vertex), 7 (destination vertex) are all connected. However, something like 3 (source vertex), 5 (destination vertex) would not be connected to the previous set of components. Could anyone guide me in the right direction or give me an idea on how to test this? Thanks!

Comment: Try a [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill). Also see [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all you do is test whether the two nodes have the same root.  If you use path compression when you build your graph, this turns out to be very fast.

---

> I think it is because I am trying to incorporate it into an
>   implementation of Kruskal's algorithm with it. After I have found all
>   connected components, I want to sort output something that will denote
>   each disjoint set from each disjoint set. Sorry to bother you so much
>   but if possible might you have any psuedo code to explain what you
>   mean?

The sets are already identified by a common root node.  **After you have done all your unions**, each unique set will have a single root.  So you then run through each node and call `Find` on it.  How about this:

```
typedef std::list< Node* > TNodeList;
typedef std::map< Node*, TNodeList > TSetMap;

TSetMap mysets;

// Assuming you have nodes stored in the list type I declared above...
for( TNodeList::iterator n = nodes.begin(); n != nodes.end(); n++ )
{
    Node *thisnode = *n;
    Node *rootnode = Find(thisnode);

    // Add to list for root.  Using the [] operator on map will create a new
    // list if none exists for that node.
    mysets[rootnode].push_back(thisnode);
}
```

Now you have a map containing all your sets as individual lists, and you can do what you like...

```
std::cout << "Number of disjoint sets: " << mysets.size() << std::endl;
int count = 0;

for( TSetMap::iterator s = mysets.begin(); s != mysets.end(); s++ )
{
    TNodeList & nl = s->second;
    std::cout << "Set " << ++count << " contains " << nl.size() << " nodes\n";
}
```

To make all these calls to `Find` efficient, you should implement path compression in your `Union` function.

Comment: The thing is I used path compression to build my graph but I can't seem to find if things have the same root or not... do you mind explaining a way to see if things have the same root or not with some psuedocode?

Comment: Shouldn't need to explain this with pseudocode.  If you have implemented path compression then you know that each node has a parent and that the path compression algorithm will ensure that the parent of every node (except a root node) is a root.  So it is very easy to test whether two nodes are in the same set, because you search for their root (either the parent or the node itself) and test if they are equal.

Comment: Hm, okay. Thank you for this. To clarify things: you simply search for the root of the node itself and test the node is equal to the root? Or am I wrong? Thanks for your patience..

Comment: No, you are trying to test whether *two* nodes are in the same set (*ie* connected).  For that, you find the root of *each* node (that's the `Find` operation of Union-Find) and test whether they are equal.  The path compression is optional -- it just makes it more efficient to do repeated `Find` operations.

Comment: Sorry I'm still not 100% on this. So would I simply use the Find function on the first node, and then use the find function on the next node, and if they're equal, then we'd have the same root, correct? I would have to have some sort of double for loop for this then to compare the first node to every other node, then compare the 2nd node to every other node, etc?

Comment: Sorry, you said that you have implemented Union-Find.  If you have, you have a function `Union(x,y)` that joins two nodes, and you have a function `Find(x)` that finds the root node of a set.  If you want to know whether `x` and `y` are related you test if `Find(x) == Find(y)`.  I don't think I can be clearer than this.

Comment: Okay. I think things are a little bit more clear... I'm just not sure what order to call my functions now. Would I simply do 

Union(Find(x),Find(y)); then followed by a if(Find(x) == Find(y)){ cout << "in a set" << endl; }

Comment: `Find` is already part of `Union`.  You need to go back to the implementation details.  Wikipedia has a good description.  Then you need to work out whether Union-Find is actually appropriate for the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I think it is because I am trying to incorporate it into an implementation of Kruskal's algorithm with it. After I have found all connected components, I want to sort output something that will denote each disjoint set from each disjoint set. Sorry to bother you so much but if possible might you have any psuedo code to explain what you mean? So sorry...

Comment: I have edited my answer with a C++ code example that should help you understand.  In this case, I simply create a list for each unique disjoint set, and added every set member to it.  Modify as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks! This was really useful. I realized I was definitely overthinking things and things make sense now. Thanks!

Comment: Ah just one question. So lets say we couldn't use maps or the STL in general. How would you do the line  mysets[rootnode].push_back(thisnode); with using only using arrays? I say this because you said in a map, using the [] operator creates a new list when none exist for that node.

Comment: Well, in that case you'd obviously have to implement your own list type.  And the easiest thing then would be to store a pointer to it on the root node of a disjoint set.  Whenever you found that the root does not yet have a list, you'd create it and add either the root node or its list to another list.  If that makes sense.  This is starting to go beyond the scope of your question, which was tagged as C++...  I would expect the STL to be part of C++.

Comment: Hm okay. I'm having trouble finding all the nodes with the same root. I was trying a double for loop (take one root, search through all the edges to see if they had the same root, move to the next root, do the same thing) but it seems repetitive and unnecessary. Is there a more efficient way to do it? Also with regards to the list class do you mind providing any psuedocode for how to do it? I've been struggling and struggling with it. I have my code posted on another post.

Comment: The code I gave you IS an efficient way to do it.  Even more efficient is my suggestion to build lists directly on the nodes, because that involves no searching and is `O(N)` in calls to `Find`.  Do not perform an `O(N^2)` loop.  If you are implementing union find, it is expected that you already understand lists.  But if not, there are *countless* examples of list implementations for both C and C++ on the web, just one search away.  If you have posted a question about lists, the correct place to answer is there, not here.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you graph is directed in which case union-find doesn't really help with connectivity (it is generally used to determine a minimum spanning tree in [Kruskal's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) if I recall correctly but this is for undirected graphs). If your graph happens to be undirected, you can use [Union-Find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union-find) to determine all connected components using a two-pass over all nodes:

1. For each node union the node with all nodes to which it has an edge.
2. For each node find the representing node and check if it was reported. If not, report it and put it, e.g., into a `std::set<T>` (for `T` being the type used to identifying the representative).

It may actually be easier to use a search algorithm like DFS:

1. For each node check if it was visited already.
2. If it wasn't visited, it is part of a new connected component: Start a DFS at the node and mark every node thus found (you can also report all the nodes encountered as being part of the connected component).

This algorithm has the advantage that it is also O(n) (the other algorithm is O(n log n) in the worst case where each connected component consists of just one node). Neither algorithm deals gracefully with directed graphs.

Comment: Yes, exactly I have a directed graph that is used to determine a minimum spanning tree via Kruskal's algorithm. Do you mind posting some psuedocode about implementing a DFS? Would a DFS be possible without using pointers? I have each vertex and length stored as an integer right now. I was thinking of using DFS but wasn't 100% sure on how to implement it...